# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory

Tags: json, jersey

Am running an application with Restful Service.And am using Jersey version 1.16 deployed in  weblogic application server.  It works in DEV server and throws error like this in QA server.

`<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1438102106438> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@546053855[app:APP module:BSWeb path:/Web spec-version:2.5]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.create(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:110)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:137)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:127)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.createXmlStreamReader(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:116)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:100)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:129)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3741)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)`

Comment: So it looks like jackson mapper jar is missing. Did you checked server classpaths? I mean all of them?

Comment: I knew that that jackson jar is reffered in jersey classes. But it works very well in QA environment. Same code deployed in two servers with same version weblogic server

Comment: There should be a the jar that includes that class file or the jar itself is under one of your server classpath folders. Also you can trace java startup classloading logs in order to see the loading directories

Answer (score 0):

[NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is a runtime exception thrown by the classloader when 'somehow' it fails to load the definition of a certain class. Many reasons can cause this exception, but in your case I believe you have two different version of Jersey in your classpath. Check your QA Web Logic classpath it might contain another version of Jerssy jar/jars.

Comment: I have checked that as well. And i have same version of jersey jars